# $S_p = \dfrac{1}{(y+z) x^p} + \dfrac{1}{(z+x) y^p} + \dfrac{1}{(x+y) z^p} \geq \dfrac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

**Main Problem:** Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers and $xyz = 1$. For any $p$ real number, let's define
$$ S_p = \dfrac{1}{(y+z) x^p} + \dfrac{1}{(z+x) y^p} + \dfrac{1}{(x+y) z^p} $$

Prove (or disprove) that for all $p\geq 2$ values, $S_p\geq \dfrac{3}{2}$.

---

**My Efforts:**

It would be helpful if I explained to the readers how I created the problem and what methods I tried.

- We show that $S_4\geq \dfrac{3}{2}$ in MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581269/how-to-prove-that-cfrac1yz-x4-cfrac1xz-y4-cfrac1yx/4581292#4581292).
- Also $S_3\geq \dfrac{3}{2}$ is a problem from [IMO-1995](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1995_IMO_Problems/Problem_2). (There are many different solution method in the link.)
- For $p=2$, I proved $S_2 = \dfrac{1}{(y+z) x^2} + \dfrac{1}{(z+x) y^2} + \dfrac{1}{(x+y) z^2} \geq \dfrac{3}{2}$.

**Proof for $p=2$ Case:** For $a,b,c$ real numbers $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq ab + bc + ca$. Also $xyz=1$ is given and so we can write $(xy)^2 + (yz)^2 + (zx)^2 \geq xy\cdot yz + zx\cdot xy + yz\cdot zx = x+y+z$. By [Sedrakyan's Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Sedrakyan%27s_lemma_-_Positive_real_numbers) of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and by the above inequality, we get

$ S_2 = \dfrac{1}{(y+z) x^2} + \dfrac{1}{(z+x) y^2} + \dfrac{1}{(x+y) z^2} \\ = \dfrac{(xyz)^2}{(y+z) x^2} + \dfrac{(xyz)^2}{(z+x) y^2} + \dfrac{(xyz)^2}{(x+y)z^2} = \dfrac{(yz)^2}{(y+z)} + \dfrac{(zx)^2}{(z+x)} + \dfrac{(xy)^2}{(x+y)} \\ \geq \dfrac{\left(xy + yz + zx \right)^2}{2(x+y+z)} = \dfrac{(xy)^2 + (yz)^2 + (zx)^2 + 2(x+y+z)}{2(x+y+z)} \\ \geq \dfrac{(x+y+z)+2(x+y+z)}{2(x+y+z)}=\dfrac{3}{2}.$

**$p=1$ Case:** If we take $x=y=2$, $z=\dfrac{1}{4}$, we can calculate the value $S_1 = \dfrac{13}{9} < \dfrac{3}{2}$. In this case, inequality is not achieved.

**$p=\dfrac{3}{2}$ Case:** If we take $x=y=4$, $z=\dfrac{1}{16}$, we can calculate the value $S_{3/2} = \dfrac{4}{65} + 8 > \dfrac{3}{2}$. In this case, inequality seems achieved. So, I felt that the inequality should be true when $p>1$. This is how the idea of the **Main Problem** came about. On the other hand, by Reza Rajaei's comment $(x,y,z) = (50,\dfrac{1}{50},1)$ and for $p=1.1$, we see that $S_{1.1}<\dfrac{3}{2}$.

- WLOG, $0 <x \leq y \leq z$. Then $x^p \leq y^p \leq z^p$ and $x+y\leq x+z \leq y+z$. I thought of using [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

$$ S_p = \dfrac{1}{(y+z) x^p} + \dfrac{1}{(z+x) y^p} + \dfrac{1}{(x+y) z^p} \leq \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{x^p} + \dfrac{1}{y^p}  + \dfrac{1}{z^p} \right) \left( \dfrac{1}{y+z} + \dfrac{1}{z+x}  + \dfrac{1}{x+y} \right) .$$
This equality is correct, but unuseful unfortunalely. Because, the inequality is in the opposite direction.

- I tried homogenizing $S_p$. $$ S_p = \dfrac{(xyz)^{(p+1)/3}}{(y+z) x^p} + \dfrac{(xyz)^{(p+1)/3}}{(z+x) y^p} + \dfrac{(xyz)^{(p+1)/3}}{(x+y) z^p} $$

and now it is homogenize. I had some more futile efforts and then I got stuck. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: It does not seem your claim is working. For example, examine $x=50, y=1, z=\frac {1}{50}, p=1.1$. I think this set is a counterexample.

Comment: @RezaRajaei thanks, you're right. I'll update it by typing the $p\geq 2$ condition instead of the $p>1$ condition. I don't know yet if $2$ is the best lower bound for $p$.

Comment: Idea 1: Calculate $\frac{dS_p}{dp}$, keeping $x,y,z$ constant. $ln(x)$ appears, and we know that $ln(x) + ln(y) + ln(z) = 0$

Idea 2: Set $z=1$, substitute $y = 1/x$, and solve the unconstrained simplified problem where the only parameters are $p$ and $x$. That might then give an idea of how to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh this one is not that bad. First, substitute $x\to\frac 1x$, etc for simplicity to obtain an equivalent inequality:
$$\sum\dfrac{x^{p-1}}{y+z}\geq \frac 32.$$ Then, do the natural Cauchy-Schwarz to obtain:
$$\sum\dfrac{x^{p-1}}{y+z}\sum (y+z)\geq  \left(\sum x^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}\right)^2.$$ But if $p\geq 2$, then $\dfrac{p-1}{2}\geq 1$ and it's an easy exercise to prove:
$$x^m+y^m+z^m\geq (xyz)^{\frac{m-1}{3}}(x+y+z)$$
when $m\geq 1.$ Combine all these together and your inequality follows.

This is proved by two C-S or equivalents, so not the most strongest inequality. I would not be surprised the optimal value of such $p$ is strictly less than $2.$

Comment: Thanks for your nice solutions. For proving the inequality $x^m+y^m+z^m \geq (xyz)^{\frac{m-1}{3}} (x+y+z)$, I used Chebyshev and AM-GM inequalities that:


$$x^m+y^m+z^m = x\cdot x^{m-1} + y\cdot y^{m-1}  + z\cdot z^{m-1} \geq \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot \left( x^{m-1} + y^{m-1}  + z^{m-1} \right)(x+y+z) \geq \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot 3 (x^{m-1}  y^{m-1}   z^{m-1} )^{1/3}(x+y+z) .$$



Starting from the main question, the use of variable substitution and other inequalities... I can say that these are difficult steps for me. I appreciate your abilities.

Comment: @dezdichado  From your reasoning follows that $S_p\geq\frac{3}{2}$ is wrong for any $p<2$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, I suspect that - but it's not immediate from what I wrote. The first usage of C-S could have been too loose.

Comment: @dezdichado It's obvious that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x^{p-1}}{y+z}\geq\frac{3}{2}$ is wrong for any $p<2$. Try $z\rightarrow0^+$ after homogenization.

Comment: @dezdichado It means $0\leq p<2$. For $p<0$ it's also interesting.

Comment: @dezdichado , if $p\geq 2$ then $m=\dfrac{p-1}{2}\geq \dfrac{1}{2}$. There is a typo about $m\geq 1$. So I tried again, with using weighted AM-GM inequality,

$\dfrac{x\cdot x^{m-1} + y\cdot y^{m-1} + z\cdot z^{m-1}}{x+y+z} \geq (x^{m-1} y^{m-1} z^{m-1})^{1/(x+y+z)} = (xyz)^{(m-1)/(x+y+z)} = 1$. 
This is another useful inequality for us.